# Time agreement. Using past simple/continuous and present perfect together

Tags: grammar, tenses, sentence

Should it be **present perfect** (*has felt*) / **present simple** (*cannot understand*) in the sentence below or the tense of the first sentence implies that these verbs fall into past aspect so **past perfect** / **past simple** pair (**backshift**) is to be applied?

> I was reading a funny article today. Its author jokingly asked whether anyone has felt himself labeled as a 'cookoo' because of his acts others cannot understand.

Comment: I'm happy with 'has felt' for looking at past occurrences, coupled with 'others cannot understand' referring to persisting character traits. I'd probably use 'asks' for a recent article.

Comment: The verb forms you used seem fine to me. :) -- In your type of sentence, the subordinate clauses can be altered to use the backshifted preterite; though, usually, that is optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default in reporting speech is to turn verbs that occur in the present tense in the actual words spoken into the past tense and to turn *can* into *could*. Doing this produces:

> I was reading a funny article today. Its author jokingly asked whether
>   anyone **had** felt himself labelled as a 'cookoo' because of his acts
>   others **could** not understand.

In this case, however, the most satisfactory solution might be to leave the verbs in the reported section as they are, and to introduce them not with *asked* but with *asks*.

Comment: Is it correct/neccessary to perform a backshift if I opt to leave the reporting verb as **asked**?

Comment: It depends on the extent to which you want to emphasise the current and continuing nature of what is described in the author's question.